# Can we create subdivisions of #pragma mark in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, optimization, pragma

We are using `#pragma` to make code more readable, accurate and separated into groups.

For example: I'm using `#pragma` like below:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma mark
#pragma mark Prefrences methods

//---------------------------------------------------------------
```

However there is something I was wondering, can we create sub section of `#pragma` in which we can divide it in one more layer.

Like I have lots of related methods like below:

[image]

You can see that these are preference related methods and can not be divide into other `#pragma`.

Just want to know whether there are any constants in Xcode like `#subpragma` or something like that which can divide `#pragma`?

Comment: Maybe with `#pragma mark — SubCategory`, and `#pragma mark #pragma mark #pragma mark Category`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibility:

Category:

```
#pragma mark 
#pragma mark Level 1
```

The two lines (two `#pragma mark`) will create a "separator".

SubCategory:

```
#pragma mark — Sublevel
```

The single line (one `#pragma mark`) will just give a title. I used a `—` to change the "indent" of the text.

Sample:

Render:
[image]
Code:

```
#pragma mark
#pragma mark Life Cycle
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {

    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark
#pragma mark Category 1

-(void)methodCategory1{}

#pragma mark — SubCat1
-(void)method1Cat1SubCat1{}
-(void)method2Cat1SubCat1{}

#pragma mark — SubCat2
-(void)method1Cat1SubCat2{}
-(void)method2Cat1SubCat2{}



#pragma mark
#pragma mark Category 2

-(void)methodCategory2{}

#pragma mark — SubCat1
-(void)method1Cat2SubCat1{}
-(void)method2Cat2SubCat1{}

#pragma mark — SubCat2
-(void)method1Cat2SubCat2{}
-(void)method2Cat2SubCat2{}
```